# Favicon with Meteor?

Tags: hyperlink, upload, directory, meteor, favicon

I'm trying to load a favicon into my Meteor project but I can't get it to work. I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054788/how-to-load-a-favicon-with-meteor) tutorial but when I put the mentioned  reference in the  of my HTML nothing happened. Also what do they mean by /public directory? I don't have a /public directory, should I just put my favicon.ico in the root directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `public` directory doesn't exist by default - you just need to create it. Meteor uses the `public` directory in the root of your app to serve plain files rather than bundling them in the app. In order for a `<link rel="icon">` tag to work, it needs to point to a file that exists in `public`. Note that the URL to the icon will not contain the path `"public/"` - files in `public` are served as if they were at the root of your web server.

A new Meteor app doesn't include any folders except the required `.meteor` directory. However, it will treat folders named `public`, `private`, `client`, `server`, and `lib` specially. You can also create more arbitrarily named directories. This affords you a lot of control over the exact structure of your app. Read about the Meteor directory structure in the [Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp):

> Lastly, the Meteor server will serve any files under the `public` directory, just like in a Rails or Django project. This is the place for images, favicon.ico, robots.txt, and anything else.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create `client/header.html`: `<head><link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico'></head>`
2. Put you `favicon.ico` into `/public` folder.
3. Start server, open your browser and see the result.