# What can affect the display of a favicon?

Tags: html, favicon

It's pretty weird but we have an app with a favicon who is working as a charm. Then my app hasn't any favicon so I decided to add the same as the one of the working app.
The working app make it like this:

```
/public/favicon.ico
```

then in `app.html/head` there is this tag `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />`

[image]
*so I made the same steps and the structure is 100% the same*

and for an unknown reason despite I made 100% the same things as this app it doesn't display the favicon, but if I go to `myapp/favicon.ico` I can see it.

The question is what could affect the favicon display ?

Comment: If the icon is at `/public/favicon.ico` the path in your link tag should be `/public/favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 0):

go a step back using `../` then enter your favicon path again like this

```
../public/favicon.ico
```

For example

My favicon in this parth  [ `/images/icons/favicon.png` ] and my html file in this path [ `/src/components/header.html` ], In this case i have to go back `../../` first two are for `components` and `src` now you're at the `root` and since you're at the root, You just have to type your path from the `root` like this  `../../images/icons/favicon.png`

Comment: should it work with localhost ? (or I need to deploy again)

Comment: Even like this (`/Users/me/Desktop/myapp/public/favicon.ico`) it doesn't work, should it work on localhost or no ?

Comment: @Jerome What is the root path of your Project files?

Comment: Could you just tell me if it should work on localhost please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054788/how-to-load-a-favicon-with-meteor founded the solution here if you edit your i'll mark as answer because it's a mistake from me to forgot to say that I'm using Meteor

Comment: @Jerome the localhost shows your project files, So you just have to identify the path to your icon inside the root(project files),